# How to configure Python Search Path in Visual Studio for Version Control?

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-2017

I've set my pip to install packages to a drive where I have more space (say `E:\pip`). In Visual Studio 2017 I've added this folder to the search path so it allows for code completion.

When I commit my project, I see that it stores the search path in the project file (`myproject.pyproj`). I tried circumventing this by adding `${PYTHONPATH}` and `${env.PYTHONPATH}` to the search directory, but Visual Studio does allow this (through the user interface at least). I read up on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/search-paths) but it does not offer best practices for version control right there. [This Github repo](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) also does not add `pyproj` to the ignore list (nor any other project file as far as I can tell).

Is there a way to have a more general search path (that I can use on multiple computers with different configurations) while still including the `pyproj` in git?

Alternatively, I could live with a "user"-specific configuration that is not included in git. A pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options for you here:

1. Using MSBuild syntax, you could specify `$(PythonPath)` as the search path. (The other syntaxes you used are for PowerShell) In Visual Studio you will see the evaluated value of this, but the entry under Project/Properties should let you modify it. Changes via Search Paths in Solution Explorer will replace the variable with the current value.
2. In Visual Studio on all machines, disable the "Ignore system-wide PYTHONPATH variables" option (see the [options reference page](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/python/python-support-options-and-settings-in-visual-studio)).
3. In Python on your machine, add a `any_name.pth` file to your site-packages directory that simply includes `E:\pip`. This will avoid the need to set `PYTHONPATH` entirely, and also avoid conflicts between interpreters (for example, if you install Python 3 packages and then run Python 2, it will see the same `PYTHONPATH` and try to import incompatible packages. With a separate `.pth` file for each installation, you can point them to different folders)

In general, search paths are expected to either be relative to the project (for example, between multiple projects in the same solution), or in a relatively standard location across machines (for example, somewhere in Program Files). Using environment variables for this purpose, especially globally (as opposed to in a script immediately before launching Python), is not encouraged.

Comment: I tried the first option, nothing appears to happen. There is no evaluation taking place, nor is the entry `$(PythonPath)` visible in the 
`Solution Explorer`. I also tried option 3, which appealed to me most. After fixing the path in the pth file (oops), this solution worked.